# UTF8Encoding string to byte[] conversion unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, string, utf-8, arrays, type-conversion

I have this piece of code:

```
byte[] bytes = ...

// Here my bytes.Lenght is 181 (for example)

var str = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);

// Here my bytes.Lenght is 189
```

Why?
How can I convert correctly the string to byte[]?

Edit: An example

```
public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public uint Age { get; set; }
}

...

Person p = new Person { Name = "Mary", Age = 24 };

string str;
byte[] b1, b2;

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, p);
    b1 = stream.ToArray();
    str = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b1);
}

b2 = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

Comment: And were the original 181 bytes a valid UTF8 sequence? There is a syntax and a set of rules involved here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Here my bytes.Lenght is 181 (for example)    
// Here my bytes.Lenght is 189
```

That can happen.

> How can I convert correctly the string to `byte[]` ?

A difference in size does not mean the conversion is invalid. The initial sequence might have been though.

If you want to preserve the size, use ASCII encoding.

---

After the expanding edit:

```
new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, p);
b1 = stream.ToArray();
str = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b1);
b2 = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

You make the assumption that a BinaryFormatter will apply  UTF8 encoding to strings.
It probably does not. It will add extra data (markers and size fields) to the stream.

So your 2 conversion (`Serialize` and `GetString` ) are just not compatible.

Aside from a difference in size, when you display the result it will probably contain some 'strange' characters.

---

#### Second Edit:

> When I deserialize the new byte array (b2) it trows an Exception

Right. What you actually need is `Convert.ToBase64String()`, not `UTF8.GetString()`

Base64 strings can be stored and transported as strings and then converted back to `byte[]` again.

Comment: When I deserialize the new byte array (b2) it trows an Exception, so I have to convert correctly my source (the string).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serialize an arbitrary `byte[]` to and from a string, don't use UTF8 encoding, use [Base64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to convert *binary* data to string with  `UTF8.GetString`(or any encoding). Use `Convert.ToBase64String` and  `Convert.FromBase64String` instead

Comment: @Nick if your bytes are not a valid UTF8 sequence it may result in strange behaviours as you see. Every byte(s) doesn't have to have a valid string representation. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for base64 encoding.